# NetSuite - Pass Data from Portlet to HTML File

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a portlet which points to an HTML file/page (Google/Bing Maps API) being hosted by NetSuite. What is the best approach for passing address data from a portlet's saved search array to the HTML file for plotting multiple map markers?

Was about to start converting my HTML file to a Suitelet for convenience, but the string literal conversion seems cumbersome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar using a trick, embedding an iframe on the portlet to include a suitelet, you should keep your logic of the saved search for the address in the suitelet and just display it on your portlet:

```
function portlet(portlet, column) {
     var url_slet = nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET', 'customscript_your_slet', 'customdeploy_your_slet');
     contentHtml += "<iframe width=100% height=100% style=height:400px; src=" + url_portlet + "></iframe>";
     portlet.setHtml(contentHtml);
}
```

Hopefully it is useful for your purpose.